# Scheduling posts in database

Tags: database, sql, wp-cron, scheduled-posts

I have more than 100 posts to schedule. I have set the date and the status (future) with a SQL query. But when the time comes the post is not published and in desktop I can read message 'Schedule lost'.

The system (cron) is working properly, because manual schedules are working normally.

How does the scheduling system work? What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scheduled Post Guardian](https://wordpress.org/plugins/scheduled-post-guardian/) solved it.

I guess scheduling strictly from database is not possible.